# Can we use Multiple TestNG Assertion in a single assertion

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am New to the Automation Testing , here i am checking the availability of the fields in the test using assertion .So could some one please help me if instead of using `Assert` for all the fields can we merge them in a single assertion. So that whatever field is not as expected it will be reported accordingly.

Below is the example:--

```
    Assert.assertTrue(Details.isFieldAvailable(storeID),storeID+ "field is not present however it is expected to be available on the form.");

    Assert.assertTrue(Details.isFieldAvailable(tdLinxID),tdLinxID+ "field is not present however it is expected to be available on the form");


    Assert.assertTrue(Details.isFieldAvailable(GLN),GLN+ "field is not present however it is expected to be available on the form");
```

Comment: You don't want to do this... if one is missing, you will get a failure but won't know which of the three is missing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. This is why there is SoftAssert.

**SoftAssert** - collects errors during @Test (no exception is thrown) and if you call org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert#assertAll at the end of @Test exception is thrown if there was any and test suite again continue with next @Test

Look into using SoftAssert.

Something like this:

```
public class SoftAsert
{
@Test
public void test()
{
    SoftAssert asert=new SoftAssert();
    asert.assertEquals(false, true,"failed");
    asert.assertEquals(0, 1,"brokedown");
    asert.assertAll();
}
}
```